# Add class to multiple of the same elements individually

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a long list of team members; when a user clicks a CTA on an individual member, a class is added to a modal box that sets it visible. However, currently every single modal window opens at the same time as they're all using the same classes.

I am wondering if it's possible to look to add the new class to the specific team member that was pressed, **I know this is possible through giving each their own class and having multiple of the same jQuery functions - but this isn't really a solution I want to go down as there are a lot, and more will be added in the future** (meaning I'll have to update the Js code for them).

Note: I'm using WordPress so am able to use PHP variables and the like.

```js
$('.modal-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.modal').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```css
.main {
  position:relative;
}

article {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  }

img {
  height: auto;
  width: 180px;
}
.content {
  padding: 30px 35px;
}
h3 {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 22pt;
  line-height: 28pt;
}
& > span {
  font-style: italic;
}
aside {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 25px;
}   
div.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: $red;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
    
 
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
}
.modal.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
.modal.visible .modal-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.modal.visible .modal-window {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal-window {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 11;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s 0.15s;
  background: $white;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <article class="team-member filter-result result-1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/85" alt="" />
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Name</h3>
      <aside>
        <div class="modal-toggle button" href="#">CLICK</div>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </article>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-overlay modal-toggle"></div>
    <div class="modal-window">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <article class="team-member filter-result result-2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/85" alt="" />
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Name</h3>
      <aside>
        <div class="modal-toggle" href="#">CLICK</div>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </article>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-overlay modal-toggle"></div>
    <div class="modal-window">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <article class="team-member filter-result result-3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/85" alt="" />
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Name</h3>
      <aside>
        <div class="modal-toggle" href="#">CLICK</div>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </article>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-overlay modal-toggle"></div>
    <div class="modal-window">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>
  </div>  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can traverse the DOM to find the modal:

```
$('.modal-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("article").next().toggleClass('visible');
});
```

`$(this)` gets a jQuery wrapper for just the element that was clicked, `.closest("article")` finds its wrapping `article` element, and `.next()` goes to the element after it (the modal).

It would be better if the `article` and the modal were both in the same wrapper element because using `.next()` is a bit fragile (what if you add an element between the `article` and the `modal`?). Then you could do `.closest("the-container").find(".modal")`. If you can't do that, you can mitigate it slightly by using `.nextAll(".modal").first()` instead:

```
$('.modal-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("article").nextAll(".modal").first().toggleClass('visible');
});
```

The jQuery object from `.nextAll` is in order from the nearest matching following sibling to the furthers, so `first` reliably gets the first one.

This is all covered in the [traversing section](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) of the jQuery API documentation, which is very thorough.

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution is to place `.modal` in the same `article` parent of `modal-toggle`. This way you can adjust your listener to target the `.modal` corresponding to the `.modal-toggle` that was clicked.

```
 $('.modal-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   //this way
  $(this).siblings('.modal').toggleClass('visible');
   // or this way or other ways too
  $(this).parent().find('.modal').toggleClass('visible');
 });
```

Comment: Better solution would be to have one `.modal` on the page that you populate with relevant data fetched from the specific `.modal-toggle` that is clicked.